# How to construct a BSONReader in mongodb java driver 3.2

Tags: mongodb-java

I have a nested document .I want to access the value for the field email
Nested Document Example:

```
   form{
      data{
           "Name": "John Smith"
           "Age": 31,
           "Info": {
                    "Email", "john.smith@mail.com"
                    "Phone", "+987654321"
                   }
         }
       }
```

How can I construct a BSON Reader for such a BSON document in mongodb java driver 3.2 .I went through documentation , but there were no clear examples on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JSON string you can simply use `Document.parse()`.

Comment: Basically I have a cursor through documents ,an with cursor.next() i have a document with me.I tried to access "email" with "form.data.Info.Email" but i guess dot operators dont work.?

Comment: No.  Dotted notation doesn't work.  You'd need `document.getDocument("form").getDocument("data")...`  etc

Comment: I also need to type check whether "form" is of type document and then apply document.getDocument("form").I need to type check each key and then go ahead with getting the values.That is were I thought BsonReader would help.Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't have a dot in a key name so all but the last element in the dotted path *must* be a document.

Comment: Hi @evanchooly thanks for helping me through.How can a array be handled in case like these say for Ex; document.getDocument("form").getDocument("data").getDocument("details"). But here details is the array of documents..........I tried .values but it gives array of object....any idea?